# Error "Service.py"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I'm new in Python and Pycharm and have some problem understanding this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\reyde\PycharmProjects\Liderws\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/reyde/PycharmProjects/Liderws/Lider_ws.py", line 48, in <module>
    browser21 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=rutaChromeDriver)
  File "C:\Users\reyde\PycharmProjects\Liderws\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\reyde\PycharmProjects\Liderws\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Liderws' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The error does say the webdriver has the wrong permissions. Is the path to ChromeDriver correct? Try to make the path something like:

```
browser21 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=C:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe)
```

Or wherever you have chromedriver saved, but make sure the path is directly to the exe.

Try redownloading the newest ChromeDriver available and place it in the folder you want. Don't forget to add it to system PATH and not just user.